# Flutter setup suddenly broken down. Can't use an expression of type 'bool Function(K)?' as a function because potentially null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

This is legitimately a case of 'b-but it worked yesterday!' Flutter was installed and set up and running. But today morning (I think Dart was updated yesterday), the template application is throwing an error on running:

```
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/material_color_utilities-0.5.0/lib/palettes/tonal_palette.dart:110:42: Error: Inferred type argument 'double?' doesn't conform to the bound 'num' of the type variable 'T' on 'min'.
Try specifying type arguments explicitly so that they conform to the bounds.
    final chroma = (tone >= 90.0) ? math.min(_chroma, 40.0) : _chroma;
                                         ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/material_color_utilities-0.5.0/lib/palettes/tonal_palette.dart:112:30: Error: The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double' because 'double?' is nullable and 'double' isn't.
        tone, () => Hct.from(_hue, chroma, tone.toDouble()).toInt());
                             ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/material_color_utilities-0.5.0/lib/palettes/tonal_palette.dart:112:36: Error: The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double' because 'double?' is nullable and 'double' isn't.
        tone, () => Hct.from(_hue, chroma, tone.toDouble()).toInt());
                                   ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/collection-1.18.0/lib/src/canonicalized_map.dart:173:60: Error: Can't use an expression of type 'bool Function(K)?' as a function because it's potentially null.
Try calling using ?.call instead.
      (key is K) && (_isValidKeyFn == null || _isValidKeyFn(key));
                                                           ^
Failed to compile application.
```

I tried running `flutter doctor` and `dart fix` and it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Perhaps also of relevance? I tried to import `charts.dart` in a project before this issue showed up. `dart fix` showed a bunch of `unnecessary_non_null_assertion` issues with it (which were fixed, but that did not solve the problem).

Running on Chrome. Flutter 3.16.6. Dart 3.2.3.

Comment: it seems there is a cache of a different version of flutter/dart making some noise, did you try flutter clean and flutter pub get? also are you using fvm?

Comment: Delete your cash files. after that you can run `flutter clean' && 1flutter pub get` command in terminal. then after you can try to run your projects. 
my be its a use-full.

Comment: Looks like you have a pre-null safety project there? https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Comment: How do you clear your cache? When I try to run `flutter clean` it gives me the same issues as when running a flutter project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.